# Python Plotly Facet Plot Y-axis title change

Tags: python, plotly, yaxis

when i ran the following:

```
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.bar(df, x="sex", y="total_bill", color="smoker", barmode="group", facet_row="time", facet_col="day",
       category_orders={"day": ["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"], "time": ["Lunch", "Dinner"]})
fig.update_layout(yaxis_title="Total Bill ($)")
fig.show()
```

The problem I encountered is that out of the 2 y-axis titles for my plot, only one of them changed to 'Total Bill ($)' and the other one stays at 'total_bill'.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUu0J.png)

Anyone knows whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-plotly option is to `rename` that column:

```
fig = px.bar(df.rename(columns={"total_bill": "Total Bill ($)"}), 
             x="sex", y="Total Bill ($)", color="smoker", barmode="group", 
             facet_row="time", facet_col="day",
             category_orders={"day": ["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"], 
                              "time": ["Lunch", "Dinner"]})
fig.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another method without changing the data column names. In this particular chart, the two y-axis titles are under yaxis1 and yaxis5, hence the code need to be:

```
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.bar(df, x="sex", y="total_bill", color="smoker", barmode="group", facet_row="time", facet_col="day",
       category_orders={"day": ["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"], "time": ["Lunch", "Dinner"]})
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        title_text="Total Bill",
    ),    
    yaxis5=dict(
        title_text="Total Bill",
    ),  
    
)
fig.show()
```

I'd imagine if the number of subplot is different then the yaxis# will be different.  One can print(fig) to figure out what the number is. Not the smartest method but it gets the job done.

Comment: Yeah when you make subplots in Plotly there are *n* axes for `x` and `y` that can be accessed that way. You can also do `fig.layout.yaxis5.title = 'Total Bill'` to set it if you like.